# K-medoids clustering with Manhattan distance

Tags: r, clustering

I have 17 numeric and 5 binary (0-1) variables, with 73 samples in my dataset.
I read about Gower distance and applied it in R with "daisy" function. After having distance matrix I used K-medoids to have clusters; "pam" fuction in R cluster package.

But I couldn't find any good results, no any significant clusters with Gower distance and K-medoids technique.

When I read about Gower, it says that; The contribution of binary variable to the total dissimilarity is 0 if both values are equal, 1 otherwise. It is same as what Manhattan does.

So I used Manhatan distance in K-medoids (pam {cluster}) and get good results, 5 cluster seems significant for my data.

Why do you think that Gower distance didn't work? I really want to use Gower distance in my project.

Comment: Define "good results", please. If you run in multiple times, does it work every time?

Comment: Thank you @Anony-Mousse. Yes, I run multuple times, gives same results. I mean, the average silhouette width is 0.5 for 5 clusters. This is better than the one with Gower distance, it was 0.25 and below for 2-3-4-5-6... clusters.

Comment: I can tell pam function not to standardize my data when I use metric=manhattan. But I can't in case of metric=Gower. I don't need to standardize my data bcs. my numeric variables are already between 0 and 1. They're in percent. May be this is the problem.

Comment: That may be the case; you should try different tools then, too. Also, values such as Silhouette are probably sensitive to the distribution of distance values - which may make them not fully comparable across different distance functions. Have you analyzed the data manually, instead of by looking at a condensed number? Usually with clustering, the only reliable evaluation is manually trying to interpret the clusters.

Comment: Yes, I am analyzing manually and trying to interpret clusters. I will try different tools. Thank you!